# How to show error for Custom View in XML Editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view, android-xml

I am developing an open source project. One of the components is a Custom View. I would like to show error in XML editor if some property is missing. Similar to what LinearLayout with multiple views does when orientation is missing.

[image]